# Permission denied: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ant, permissions

I am new to `maven` and `tomcat` . I have a project in that I was running tomcat in a debugging mode .So, I was running `tomcat7:run` while running I was facing the following issue.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (copy-service-config) on project  Error executing ant tasks: {{Project path}}target/antrun/build-Copy file 
-Copy files to web project.xml (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
```

Can any one please help me with this ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have permission to do the copy? Maybe the target file is in the program files folder in Windows in which case you would need administrator access.

Comment: I am using ubuntu machine.